# What does "antisymmetric" mean for the adjoint map of a Lie algebra?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, geodesic

A theorem about Lie algebras says that:

Fix a Lie group $G$, endowed with a left invariant riemannian metric $g$, let $\nabla$ be the Levi Civita connection. Let the Lie algebra of $G$ be $\mathfrak{g}$ then the following are equivalent:

1. The adjoint map of $\mathfrak{g}$ is such that $ad(X)$ is antisymmetric $\forall X\in\mathfrak{g}$
2. The one parameter subgroups of $G$ are precisely the (Levi-Civita) geodetics of $G$

Now my question is not about the theorem, but about the meaniing of the first condition. To my understanding $ad$ is a linear map $X\in\mathfrak{g}\mapsto ad(\mathfrak{g})\in \mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})\cong Hom(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g})$ where $ad(X): Y\in\mathfrak{g}\mapsto [X,Y]\in \mathfrak{g}$. So it is a linear map, and not multinear map: how can it be antisymmetric? Wat do we mean by this term here? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hate acronyms :(

Comment: @Miguel I will edit, though I thought TFAE was pretty widespread!

Comment: Another data point: I'd have no idea what "TFAE" would abbreviate...

Comment: Ok I beg your pardon, mine must have been a wrong impression, thank for the feedback. I edited, anyhow.

Comment: To add a further data point. TFAE has been used by dozens of seminar speakers at my university, all of my undergraduate lecturers, etc.

Comment: Can you give an example of this in a citation? As it stands, you are right, but I expect there's some context missing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there exists an underlying differentiable left invariant scalar product, antisymmetric means $\langle ad_x(y),z\rangle+\langle y,ad_x(z)\rangle=0$.

If they do not talk about the metric and the group is semi-simple take the Killing form.

Comment: Isn't the Killing form always skew-symmetric with respect to the adjoint map?

Comment: skew symmetric means $b(v,w)=-b(w,v)$.

Comment: Yes the left invriant metric is there! Somehow I took it for granted, now I will update the question. Thanks a lot: I had never heard of such a notion of antisymmetry. Moreover in italian skew simmetry and antisimmetry are  translated the same, sadly.

Comment: So what does anti-symmetric mean to you then, if it isn't the same as skew-symmetric?